# Защита от прямого скачивания не работает

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла проблема с htaccess при включении защиты картинок от использования с других доменов. Вот часть строк файла:

```
#ерунда всякая
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ - [F,L]
RewriteBase /
#далее - код от CMS'ки
```

При этом CMS работает, но картинки спокойно отображаются и на других доменах. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

**Дополнено**
`<a href="http://domain.com/img/img.jpg"><img src="http://domain.com/img/img.jpg"></a>`
Как я понимаю, ни картинка не должна отображаться, ни переход по ссылке не должен на нее вести. Правильно?

Comment: А разве в синтаксисе HTACCESS "-" не означает "ничего не делать"? Может я конечно ошибаюсь но попробуйте заменить RewriteRule на что-то типа:

    RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ http://domain.com/ [R,L]

Comment: Там же флаг `[F]` - по идее, должен выдаваться статус Forbidden.  
Сделал вашим способом. Та же история. =(

Comment: @ling откопаешь ответ, скинь плз... Грабли нужно хранить!

Comment: А остальное из Htaccess то работает? То что относится к cms'ки. Может Htaccess на сервере просто напросто отключен?

Comment: @Palmervan, обязательно. =)

Comment: > `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?domain\.com [NC]`

Конечно, вряд-ли проблема в этом, но в регулярке ошибка - точка после www не экранирована.

А вообще, для отладки rewrit'ов нужно добавить:

    RewriteLog "/path/to/file.log" 
    RewriteLogLevel 3

И смотреть лог.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov почему тогда на локале без экранизации точек все найс? НЕ уж то Вы думаете что у множества на локалхосте так все быдловски настроено?

Comment: @Palmervan, я же написал, что вряд-ли эта ошибка имеет отношение к вопросу. Или вы комментарии только наполовину читаете?

А для того, что бы ответить на вопрос и не гадать на кофейной гуще, нужен отладочный лог.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Та же история. И картинки можно ставить с других доменов, и переход по ссылке на картинку происходит. Может, надо соблюсти какие-то условия, о которых я не знаю?

Comment: Видимо надо... о которых я тоже незнаю... Просмотрел на результат этого вопроса vs ответа десяток форумов, везде почти одно и тоже, хотя правило давно валяется у меня... хз, может у хостера вафли?

Comment: за вопрос заплюсадинил, самому тиресно почему не работает?..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.png|.gif|.jpg|.jpeg)$ / [F,L]
```

По крайней мере, проверил у себя на локале, все работает.
Если что-то не так, то скорее всего это хостер виноват.

Comment: У меня на локале и мой работает! Темнота видимо в другом!